# NullPointerException on getClass().getResource not working for Apache Spark

Tags: java, maven, apache-spark, classpath

I have a maven project, and I am using some resources written in files. In order to add them to the classpath, in the POM file I define it as follows:

```
<build>
    <!-- custom resource folders -->
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

and the resource folders I am using are:

1. `src/main/resources/A-resources`
2. `src/main/resources/B-resources`

So, in both folders `A-resources` and `B-resources` I have some files from which I want to read stuff. I have the following code for reading some options from these files:

```
try {
    // Error appears on the next line ("InputStream in = ... ")
    InputStream in = getClass().getResource("/A-resources/some_file.conf").openStream();
    setOptions(in); // -> some function for reading options from files
    in.close();     
} catch (IOException e) {
    // should not happen
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Locally, this works fine. However, when I build a fat jar for running the whole code on Spark on a cluster, it throws a NullPointerException.

I suspect that, although they are built in the classpath, the resources maybe are not exported in the fat jar. How can I fix the problem? Maybe with some additional options in the POM file?

**EDIT:**

When I check the fat jar, I can see the file is there:

```
...
714 Wed Jun 07 11:14:58 CEST 2017 resources/A-resources/some_file.conf
...
```

If I change:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResource("/A-resources/some_file.conf").openStream();
```

to

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResource("/resources/A-resources/some_file.conf").openStream();
```

it will work on Spark (so, by changing everything in the code to add this `/resources` as a prefix). However, with this change - the local part doesn't work. How do I make this to work for both, that is, instead of having in the fat jar this:

```
resources/A-resources/some_file.conf
```

to have it directly:

```
A-resources/some_file.conf
```

Comment: The most likely explanation is that the resource path is incorrect.  Check the JAR file to see what has been included in it, and what the actual path is.

Comment: Thanks, this almost solved the problem (see edit). Although it works for spark, now the local part is broken. Any idea how to make it work for both?

Comment: @StephenC: your comment led to correct solution of the problem. Please form an answer from your comment and my edit so I can accepted as an answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I commented:

> The most likely explanation is that the resource path is incorrect. Check the JAR file to see what has been included in it, and what the actual path is.

Aside: Running `jar -tvf` will give you a list of all resources in a JAR file.

It turns out that that *was* the root of your problem.  (Sometimes educated guesses turn out to be correct ...  )

You replied:

> Thanks, this almost solved the problem (see edit). Although it works for spark, now the local part is broken. Any idea how to make it work for both?

Looking at what you have discovered, and what you said you then did, I think you to the wrong approach to fixing the problem.  It looks to me like the path that you were using originally in your code was correct: it made sense, and it worked in the local case.

My diagnosis would have been that there was a problem in the way you were building the JAR file.  Take a look at the POM file.

Based on what I read in ["Specifying Resource Directories"](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html), I think that your POM file should have a separate `<resource>dir</resource>` for each of your resource directories.

If that doesn't help, take a look at any POM configs that relate to Maven building the JAR file.